# COUNTIFS problem with 30, 60, 90 days range

Tags: excel, countif

I'm trying to search for a text in column and if this item is between 31-60 or 61-90 from today's date, but it doesn't return any count
any one can help?

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!B2:B21,">="&TODAY()+31,Sheet2!B2:B21,"<="&TODAY()+60,Sheet2!A2:A21,"A")

=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!B2:B21,">="&TODAY()+61,Sheet2!B2:B21,"<="&TODAY()+90,Sheet2!A2:A21,"A")
```

Comment: Your formulas have a third condition that looks for cells containing "A" in the range A2:A21. Is that what you want? Beign so, formulas work for me.

Comment: How are the cells in column B formatted?

Comment: yes @Evil Blue Monkey this is what im trying to get a text criteria from a drop down menu , and if date reported passed 30, 60 , 60 days, but it doesn't retrieve any count (always 0)and i made sure that date reported passed 30 days and another scenario passed 60 days.

Comment: @SolarMike formatted as date

Comment: Then i see no reason why it shouldn't work. Screen updating is on? Are you sure that dates are formatted and are actually entered as date? If you type =B2+1 in a cell does it give back the next date? Is the letter value free from any space (like "A ")?